# How to implement virtual coins attached with real money in xamarin.forms app

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I need to integrate virtual coins into my xamarin forms application. User can like to buy them, so and exchange back to real money. Please tell me how can I implement it? What payment system to use for depositing and withdrawing money?

Comment: This is far too broad for Stack Overflow - I'd recommend taking the [tour] and reading [ask]. In addition, what you are describing is a legal minefield as you're effectively creating a currency, which comes with all sorts of fun anti-money laundering legislation attached to it, so I'd probably reconsider.

Answer (score 0):

This is very broad question you are asking. However seems like you are very new to Stack overflow. You should follow the guidelines. You should ask very specific question, and should post whatsoever you have done. Any exceptions you get or anything that is helpful resolving the issue. Again, creating the virtual coins is huge topic however I will try to make it simple:

1. Create the backend and implement the coin services
2. Coin services like Buy Coin, Withdraw coin to bank
3. You should create the Merchant account to be able to do Credit/Debit card transaction to buy your coins from your customers using the app.
4. You can signup for BrainTree, Square etc. They will give you the sandbox to implement.

Here's the use case detail to understand how it works:

- Lets say; When a user goto your app and say Buy 1000 coins,
- That request goes to your Webservices
- Your webservice will Talk to your merchant server then return the Token to your app to go further.
- Your app receives the token then your app will use the Payment nonce which you should submit back to your webservice
- With the payment nonce your backend will Create the sale transaction to your merchant server.
- Your backend will update current users Coin - say it will add 1000 to the last value.
- Your app will return Success/failure to your app at the end and your app can proceed based on that response.

Hope this gives you some idea how it works. I hope you are not asking for any crypto currency implementation as "Virtual currency".

If you want to learn about BrainTree, Read more here in Braintree documentation https://developers.braintreepayments.com/
Atleast it will give you the idea how it works.